# Adipoli jQuery overlayText

Tags: jquery, hover

i'm using Adipoli jquery plugin for image overlays (from grey to color over..but now i want to add a text caption too.. http://jobyj.in/adipoli/ it says it has a text overlay function (under Available options) But dont know how to add the text over my image in the html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
    $(function()
    {
        $('.row6').adipoli(
        {
            'overlayText' : '<b>overlayText</b>',
            'startEffect' : 'grayscale',
            'hoverEffect' : 'normal',
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

The html code is below:

```
<div class="box1"><a href="#"><img class="img-style row6" src="images/imagen_box1.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: did you find any solution? I need same feature.

Answer (score 0):

After 'hoverEffect':'normal' property

no coma(,) required..

```
$('.row6').adipoli(
            {
                'overlayText' : '<b>overlayText</b>',
                'startEffect' : 'grayscale',
                'hoverEffect' : 'normal'
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but still cant get the hover text to show...Do you think if i show you the live link you can help me?

Comment: I had to do another option... and i'm using another hover effect.. was to hard to execute. Now im using a Jquery to show only the caption an a simple code in the html to show the image in another color (creating 2 images) - will love to add this last effect to a jquery.. but weil see.. thanks for your hel anyway!